# SSL TLS renegotiation vulnerability - current situation in clients

Tags: tls, web-browser, known-vulnerabilities, protocols

Reading about the SSL renegotiation problem [CVE-2009-3555](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555) one knows that servers supporting old type of renegotiation are vulnerable to data injection. We also have tools to test them (`openssl s_client` and [Qualsys SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html)).

But what's the situation with clients? After checking the https://ssltls.de site using few browsers, it would seem that the only two browsers that have fixed this problem are Firefox (since 3.5.9 and 3.6.2) and Opera (since 11.00 or 10.50?).

Browsers that are still vulnerable according to the site are:

- Chrome 9.0.597.16
- Chrome 12.0.742.124 (!)
- Chrome 13.0.782.56 beta
- Chrome 14.0.825.0 dev
- Internet Explorer 9 (!)
- Konqueror 4.6.3

Is this test reliable? Or is the situation really this grim?

Edit:
Is there a way to use `openssl s_server` to test client's vulnerability?

Comment: Safari 5.1 on Mac OS Lion is still vulnerable.

Comment: @Wei Hu: According to the site ssltls.de, or did Apple still not applied a quick hack (disable renegotiation)?

Comment: According the cite you linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All current versions of the major browsers (IE/FF/Chrome) are actually patched with the fix for secure renegotiation.

The ssltls.de site has some problems it seems, as I went to it using different browsers, different network connections, and I got inconsistent results. Wireshark shows the browsers sending the extension and server replying to it, so it seems the test can be improved to better detect the extension.

Comment: Now that is interesting!

Comment: For one, the use of different port numbers was blocked by the proxy on one of the connections I used. That immediately flaged *all* browsers as vulnerable.